# Convert queries to expected array efficiently - Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I have a `dictionaries` table looks like this:
[image]

Here is the array result that I want:
[image]

I've already achieved the result by these ugly code:

```
    $dictionaries = Dictionary::all();
    $carriers_array = [];
    $carriers = $dictionaries->unique('Carrier');
    foreach($carriers as $carrier) {
        $carriers_array[] = $carrier->Carrier;
    }

    $DOM_INLs_array = [];
    foreach($carriers_array as $carrier_item) {
        $DOM_INLs = $dictionaries->where('Carrier', $carrier_item)->unique('DOM_INL');
        foreach($DOM_INLs as $DOM_INL) {
            $DOM_INLs_array[$carrier_item][] = $DOM_INL->DOM_INL;
        }
        
    }

    $groups_array = [];
    foreach($DOM_INLs_array as $carrier => $DOM_INLs) {
        foreach($DOM_INLs as $DOM_INL) {
            $groups = $dictionaries->where('Carrier', $carrier)->where('DOM_INL', $DOM_INL)->unique('Group');
            foreach($groups as $group) {
                $groups_array[$carrier][$DOM_INL][] = $group->Group;
            }
        }
    }

    $routes_array = [];
    foreach($groups_array as $carrier => $DOM_INLs) {
        foreach($DOM_INLs as $DOM_INL => $groups) {
            foreach($groups as $group) {
                $routes = $dictionaries->where('Carrier', $carrier)->where('DOM_INL', $DOM_INL)->where('Group', $group)->unique('Route');
                foreach($routes as $route) {
                    $routes_array[$carrier][$DOM_INL][$group][] = $route->Route;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $sectors_array = [];
    foreach($routes_array as $carrier => $DOM_INLs) {
        foreach($DOM_INLs as $DOM_INL => $groups) {
            foreach($groups as $group => $routes) {
                foreach($routes as $route) {
                    $sectors = $dictionaries->where('Carrier', $carrier)->where('DOM_INL', $DOM_INL)->where('Group', $group)->where('Route', $route)->unique('Sector');
                    foreach($sectors as $sector) {
                        $sectors_array[$carrier][$DOM_INL][$group][$route][] = $sector->Sector;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    dd($sectors_array);
```

But it runs very slow, I want another way to get the same result but more efficient. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your query as well.

Comment: @AhmadKarimi I updated the question which included the query of `$dictionaries`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bunch of nested `map`s and `groupBy`s with a `pluck` at the end:

Arrow functions, PHP 7.4+:

```
$dictionaries->groupBy('Carrier')
    ->map(fn ($i) => $i->groupBy('DOM_INL')
        ->map(fn ($i) => $i->groupBy('Group')
            ->map(fn ($i) => $i->groupBy('Route')
                ->map->pluck('Sector')
            )
        )
    );
```

With anonymous functions:

```
$dictionaries->groupBy('Carrier')->map(function ($i) {
    return $i->groupBy('DOM_INL')->map(function ($i) {
        return $i->groupBy('Group')->map(function ($i) {
            return $i->groupBy('Route')->map->pluck('Sector');
        });
    });
});
```

**If** you only needed these results grouped in this way and didn't need the leaves to just be the 'Sector' values this would be 1 call to `groupBy`:

```
$dictionary->groupBy(['Carrier', 'DOM_INL', 'Group', 'Route'])
```

Comment: Your solution looks promising, but these code look like the new version of php, could give me the code that's compatible with old php version?

Comment: sure, check the update and see if that works for you

Comment: I just had another problem. That is, to get the current results, I have to query the entire table and load all the results into memory. If the table only had 10,000 rows back, I wouldn't have a problem.

However, if the table has 100 thousand rows, 200 thousand rows or more ... each query will take up 1GB of memory or more, leading to server death. The VPS I am using only has 2GB of memory ... do you have a way to help me solve the memory usage problem and still get the same results as now?